# How to optimize number of threads needed

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, udp, sniffer

I am building an UDP port scanner in C.
This is a scheme of the code

```
Create Socket
Structure raw UDP packet with port i 
Send packet and wait n miliseconds for reply
```

I need to perform those tasks X times, depending on the number of ports to be scanned. It may be up to 65535 times.

My goal is to optimize resources, considering  an i386 machine running under a 3.5.0-17-generic Linux kernel.

1. How many threads should be created?
2. How many packets should be sent inside a single thread?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: using the term pseudo-code quite loosely I see.

Answer (score 1):

1. One thread, using `select`, `epoll` or similar.
2. All of them. Remember to rate limit since that doesn't happen automatically with UDP.

Comment: These kids learn too much java these days that they want to solve all the problems with threads :(